# Is there a better way to say "space for improvement"?

Tags: alternatives

In the following sentence, is there a better word to use instead of *space*?

*"A lot of space remains for improvement and future work"*

To add some context, the sentence is from a paper on database storage integration (i.e. computer science).

Comment: Opportunities sounds better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although *room* and *space* are mostly synonymous, [**room for improvement** is much more idiomatic than *space for improvement.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=room%20for%20improvement%2Cspace%20for%20improvement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croom%20for%20improvement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspace%20for%20improvement%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: can you use it in the stated sentence, though? _A lot of room remains for improvement and future work?_

Comment: @JanPisl - *room for improvement* is pretty informal, and the way I would use it is "There's a lot of room for improvement and future work."  Because it's idiomatic, it doesn't quite sound right when you change the word order around.

Comment: +1, *idiomatic* being the operative word here. While "space" isn't *ungrammatical*, it sounds odd to an experienced ear.